# Assigning labels to values in columns after sequential sorting in R

Tags: r, dataframe, columnsorting

I have a data frame that looks like one that can be replicated with following code:

```
 reproduce.df <- rbind.data.frame(replicate(6,sample(1:50, 50, rep = TRUE)),replicate(6,sample(NA, 5, rep = TRUE)),replicate(6,sample(1:50, 50, rep = TRUE)))
```

1. I want to cut the data in column 1 into 3 parts and assign them 3 labels based on lowest to highest tercile. (Let's say the labels are 1,2,3)
2. After assigning labels to data in column 1, i want to assign labels in column 2 by first grouping the values in column 1 by each of the three variables and then assigning label named 1 to 3 in each of these 3 groups as per terciles.
   For eg. the lowest tercile values in column 1 will have the label "1". For all 1's in column 1, i want to create terciles based on values in column 2 and assign the labels "1","2","3" to them.
3. This process is repeated again in 3rd column after merging the labels for data in column 1 & 2. This way, for the third column data, we have 27 unique labels.
4. This process is again repeated in columns 4 to 6.

What i have tried:
used cut function to assign labels in column 1 and added it to the data frame. The code is as follows:

```
labels.v1 <- cut(reproduce.df[,1], quantile(reproduce.df[,1], seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 4), na.rm = TRUE), labels = seq(1:3), include.lowest = TRUE)

reproduce.df2 <- cbind.data.frame(reproduce.df,labels.v1)
```

However, i am not able to extend this logic to the next step.
For the next step, I used 'by' function to split the data frame into 3 parts based on column 1 labels and then assign labels to these 3 parts.

```
by(reproduce.df2$V2, reproduce.df2$labels.v1, FUN = function(x) cut(x, quantile(x, seq(from=0,to=1,length.out = 4), na.rm = TRUE), labels = c("1","2","3"), include.lowest = TRUE))
```

Though this works, but the output it gives is in a list format and cannot be directly merged with the data frame. Also, it remove NA's from the data frame and i would like to keep the NA's as these columns are a part of a larger data frame and i would like to just merge the labels withing that data frame.

How can i do this procedure in R?

Comment: sample(NA, n, replace=TRUE) is the same as logical(n), btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)

DF[, v := ""]    
for (k in names(DF)[1:6]){
  DF[!is.na(get(k)), v := paste0(v, cut(get(k), 3, FALSE)), by=v]
  DF[is.na(get(k)), v := paste0(v, "-")]
}

     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6      v
  1: 42 33 10  8 26 35 321122
  2: 21 35 42 46  9  2 233322
  3: 10 26 18 25 40 17 121232
  4: 22 35 26 34  3  1 232322
  5: 26 30 23  2 23 24 222122
 ---                         
101: 25 26 18  8 31 24 221123
102:  2 37 13 28 34 33 131232
103: 10  5 14 20 33 29 111122
104: 27 50 18  1 18 33 231112
105: 16 42 23  3 14 35 132122
```

I tried using `ave` from base R to do this, but it was too annoying to handle.

The stand-in value `-` is used because leaving as blank or NA does not make sense if some columns are missing and others are not within a row.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's really helpful and concise. I just wanted to clarify a couple of things. Does the value in 4th column come from grouping in 3rd column and then dividing into terciles or it's just on an individual basis. Also, i set the seed at 1001 and compared the results of your code and the code given by Mark. There is a minor difference between the two. For eg. in the second row, the first 3 column results with Mark's code is 212 and the same result with your code is 222. Can you suggest which one is better?

Comment: I checked. When i change the "3" inside the cut function to breaks=quantile(get("V1"),seq(0,1,length.out=4),na.rm=T),labels=FALSE,include.lowest=TRUE , then it gives same results. I think that to divide them into equal parts, we need to use the quantile function as the argument breaks=3  divides the data into 3 intervals of equal length instead.

Comment: @Vaibhav Ah, I guess you're right. However, when I defined `cuteq = function(x, n) cut(x, breaks = quantile(x, seq(0, 1, length.out=n+1), na.rm=TRUE), labels=FALSE, include.lowest=TRUE)`, I find that it gives an error if `x` has length 1, e.g., `cuteq(20, 3)`. I guess some management of edge cases is needed. When I wrap `quantile` in `unique`, I get a different error.

Comment: Shouldn't x be a vector instead of a scalar quantity?

Comment: @Vaibhav The issue is that you will eventually have scalars if nrow(DF) < 3^ncol(DF), right? Maybe I misunderstood the question; I thought it was computing on successively smaller groups (one third of data, one third of that, etc).

Comment: You understood the question correctly. It's just that in my case, the no of iterations won't be so many as to arrive at a point where nrow(DF) < 3^ncol(DF). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to just use base R, this can be done but it would be much easier with `dplyr` or even `data.table`.

The first problem you identify is that `by` returns a list.  You can simply `unlist()`  the output to have a vector.  *but* this creates a new problem - your original data isn't sorted and so the unlisted data won't be in the correct order.  So, first we need to sort the data.

```
reproduce.df2 <- cbind.data.frame(reproduce.df,labels.v1)[order(labels.v1),]
labels.v2 <- unlist(by(reproduce.df2$V2, reproduce.df2$labels.v1, FUN = function(x) cut(x, quantile(x, seq(from=0,to=1,length.out = 4), na.rm = TRUE), labels = c("1","2","3"), include.lowest = TRUE)))
```

But now you have a new problem - the NAs of your data frame, specifically of `labels.v1` don't get included so `labels.v2` is too short now.  You'd need to filter out any row that has an NA for this to work.  For your next steps you'd need to being pasting the label columns together for sorting to get nested sorting working properly.

What about using `dplyr` then?

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1001)
reproduce.df <- rbind.data.frame(replicate(6,sample(1:50, 50, rep = TRUE)),replicate(6,sample(NA, 5, rep = TRUE)),replicate(6,sample(1:50, 50, rep = TRUE)))
breaks <- seq(0,1,length.out=4)
reproduce.df <- mutate(reproduce.df,labels.v1 = cut(V1,quantile(V1,breaks,na.rm=T),labels=FALSE,include.lowest=TRUE))
reproduce.df <- group_by(reproduce.df,labels.v1)
reproduce.df <- mutate(reproduce.df,labels.v2 = cut(V2,breaks=quantile(V2,breaks,na.rm=T),labels=FALSE,include.lowest=TRUE))
reproduce.df <- group_by(reproduce.df,labels.v1,labels.v2)
reproduce.df <- mutate(reproduce.df,labels.v3 = cut(V3,breaks=quantile(V3,breaks,na.rm=T),labels=FALSE,include.lowest=TRUE))
```

At each step you add the previous label to your `group_by` and `mutate` (create a variable) the new labels.

Note - I set `labels = FALSE` because it wasn't working with specifying the labels `1:3`. This way it just outputs an integer 1 through 3 anyway.

You can see the output at the end of the code above below.

```
> arrange(reproduce.df,labels.v1,labels.v2,labels.v3)
# A tibble: 105 x 9
# Groups:   labels.v1, labels.v2 [10]
      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6 labels.v1 labels.v2 labels.v3
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>
 1     5     3     3     9    10    34         1         1         1
 2     3     2    13    15     7    11         1         1         1
 3    14     5    24    16    19     3         1         1         1
 4     5    14    20     3    45    34         1         1         1
 5     4    17     3    15    16    12         1         1         1
 6     1    15    41    15    48    47         1         1         2
 7    15     4    31    29    39    25         1         1         2
 8    15     8    26    41    42     8         1         1         2
 9     4    11    28    45    11    46         1         1         2
10     5    13    46    42    34    18         1         1         3
# ... with 95 more rows
```